# Using SQL Profiler can I pinpoint to one DB

Tags: sql-server

Can I pinpoint SQL Profiler just to one Database, my server has around 50 Database and I just want SQL Profiler to check one Database because the site that uses that Database has gone very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

When you set your trace up, go to the Events Selection tab and click the "Show all columns" checkbox. Then the Database column appears and you can put a filter on the database name in Column Filters.